# Calculate item depth in PHP from a flat array with only a parent item ID

Tags: php, arrays, depth

I have a flat array:

```
Array
    (
    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 346788
            [parent_id] => 0
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [parent_id] => 0
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56745
            [parent_id] => 12346
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3564
            [parent_id] => 12346
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2345234
            [parent_id] => 56745
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [id] => 433546
            [parent_id] => 56745
            [item_title] => 'title Here'
            [item_description] => 'some text'
        )
)
```

that has each item's ID as a key/value pair as well as the parent item's id. First thing that needs to happen is the flat array needs to be turned into a hierarchical array, while simultaneously preserving all of the other information that is with each of the array items. the trick part is that i need to know the depth of that item in the array as a 0 based level. so the parent will be 0 first child will be 1, etc etc and have it stored in the final array:

```
function build_tree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0, $depth = 0) {

    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as &$element) {

        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = build_tree( $elements, $element['id'], $depth + 1 );
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            $branch[$element['id']]['depth'] = $depth;
            unset($element);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
```

Second, I also need an additional function that can calculate the depth from the original flat array:

```
function calculate_depth( $item_id, array $array ) {

    return $item_depth;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you get a depth from build_tree() ?

Comment: @Yurich I am modifying someone else's software and it's easier to build it in two parts then rebuild the entire thing to utilize the new tree structure.

Answer (score 4):

I you don't have access to the tree, what you need would anyway involve a complete scan of the array, so I'd use a hashmap:

```
$map = array();
foreach ($elements as $e)
  $map[$e['itemID']] = array(
    'parent' => $e['parentID'],
    'depth' => null
  );
```

So, to get a depth you'd scan this parents map now, which would take time proportional to the depth:

```
function depth(&$map, $id) {
    $depth = 0;
    $the_id = $id;
    while ($map[$id]['parent']) {
      if ($map[$id]['depth'] !== null) {
        $depth += $map[$id]['depth'];
        break;
      }
      $id = $map[$id]['parent'];
      $depth++;
    }
    $map[$the_id]['depth'] = $depth;
    return $depth;
}
```

In the code above a added a little caching mechanism, so that the computation of all depths would still take linear time.